# Keep MySQL connection open to submit multiple queries from shell

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I'd like to learn more about how the MySQL command line tool works.

Suppose I would like to be able to script multiple SQL statements and use shell scripting to output a description of the statements as they are processed. Here's a generic example where del_sql, ins_sql, and qry_sql would refer to any delete, insert, and select query on the same data set.

```
echo "Deleting data in the range."
echo $del_sql | mysql -h "$mysql_host" -u "$mysql_user" -p"$mysql_pass" -D "$mysql_db"

echo "Inserting data into the range."
echo $ins_sql | mysql -h "$mysql_host" -u "$mysql_user" -p"$mysql_pass" -D "$mysql_db"

echo "Querying data from the range."
echo $qry_sql | mysql -h "$mysql_host" -u "$mysql_user" -p"$mysql_pass" -D "$mysql_db"
```

What I'm concerned about is - does this open and close three separate connections to the database, and is this more expensive than submitting all statements at once? In this example suppose that all_sql is a string containing all three statements separated by semicolons.

```
echo "Deleting, inserting, and querying data in the range."
echo $all_sql | mysql -h "$mysql_host" -u "$mysql_user" -p"$mysql_pass" -D "$mysql_db"
```

I tried the following just messing around with it, thinking it would make sense.

```
mysql -h "$mysql_host" -u "$mysql_user" -p"$mysql_pass" -D "$mysql_db"
echo $del_sql | mysql -e
echo $ins_sql | mysql -e
echo $qry_sql | mysql -e
```

But this is clearly incorrect syntax.

Comment: Not sure what the question is, but if you want to feed multiple lines to a command, why don't you use here-is input?

Comment: The question is: do you have to put the MySQL credentials in every time you run a MySQL command and why? Can you not just maintain an active open connection?

What do you mean here-is input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no programmer, but on database side I can tell you, that MySQL handles this quite efficiently for you. It uses a thread cache / pool. Each thread is basically a connection.

You can read more about it here: [How MySQL Uses Threads for Client Connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connection-threads.html).

And you can even observe this, when you log into your database via command line client and then issue your script in another shell.

Do a

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

After your script ran through, you will see that your connection is still there with the status `SLEEPING`. It will be reused when you execute your script again.

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you!