# execute mysql query from a bash loop without reconnecting each time?

Tags: mysql, bash, loops

I have a file with strings in each line and I need to check in any of strings matches strings in a column of a table. If I do this, it reconnects every time, which is not efficient. I also tried full-text search, but since my strings in the file have dots (.), it splits them and also matches substrings. I need exact matches.

```
while IFS= read -r LINE; do
   mysql -u USER -pPASS -D DB  mysql -e "select * from TABLE where FIELD='$LINE'"
done < input.txt
```

What would be the best way to do this?
thanks

Comment: This will answer your concern on multiple connenctions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617222/keep-mysql-connection-open-to-submit-multiple-queries-from-shell

Comment: Just to mention that the file has tens of thousands of lines... One of the problems is that I get the column names for each match, which is quite annoying.

Comment: Maybe you can skip column names likes this, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_skip-column-names